# How to use TextReader to read string and further use it with CsvReader() for getting records in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

How to use TextReader to read string and further use it with CsvReader() for getting records in c#?

I'm getting 0 list count.

After passing .csv file contents into a string and then TextReader and use it with CsvReader

Comment: Can you please add some code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]